# Calculate complex limit converging to constant $e$.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I'm stuck for calculating the following complex limit:

$$
\lim_{z \to 0}{(1+z)^{\frac{1}{z}}}
$$

This is the complex version of the real version of limit converging to $e$. (and [wolfram says the complex version also converges to $e$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28a%2Cb%29-%3E%280%2C0%29+%281%2Ba%2Bb+i%29%5E%281%2F%28a%2Bb+i%29%29)) Therefore I guessed that applying the definition of limit ($\epsilon\text{-}\delta$) with $e$ is the way to go.

However I cannot get further. Firstly I guessed that the idea of the proof of the real version of limit might help, but it did not help my brain.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of raising complex numbers to complex powers is given by

$$a^b \equiv e^{b\log a}$$

for some choice of branch cut of $\log$ (when no other information is present, the principal branch of $\log$ is assumed). In this case we have that

$$(1+z)^{\frac{1}{z}} = \exp\left(\frac{\log(1+z)}{z}\right)$$

Since $\exp$ is continuous, we can move the limit in, leading us to find

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\log(1+z)}{z} = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\log(1+z)-\log 1}{z} \equiv (\log z)'\Bigr|_{z=1} = 1$$

which makes the original limit $e$ (as it turns out the branch cut does not matter here because the limit does not need to encircle the origin in $\log$. $\log$ is always differentiable in a neighborhood of $1$).

Comment: If one chooses to define the logarithm as $\log(1+z)=\text{Log}(|1+z|)+i\arg(1+z)$ where $0\le \arg(1+z)<2\pi$, then how would you propose to proceed?  The origin lies on the branch cut.

Comment: @MarkViola good point, the caveat being the branch cut does not matter as long as you don't cut it at the point you care about. But usually I have seen the cuts exclude the branch from the domain ($\leq \to <$) so the issue doesn't arise.

Comment: Well even if the branch is excluded, we still have a problem for $z\to 0$.  The limit taken from the upper-half plane is $e$ here.  But there is no limit taken from the lower-half plan since $\lim_{z\to 0}e^{i2\pi/z}$ fails to exist. ;-) … So, we need only ensure that the branch cut does not pass through the origin.

Answer (score 0):

In elementary calculus, the approach to limits having the form $\left[ 1^\infty \right]$ is to use the continuous exponential and logarithm functions to push the base into the exponent then move the limit through the continuous functions.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} (1+z)^{1/z} &= \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \exp \ln \left( (1+z)^{1/z} \right)  \\
&= \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \exp \frac{\ln (1+z)}{z}  \\
&= \exp \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln (1+z)}{z}
\end{align*}
As you can see this approach has converted the limit to the form $\left[ \frac{0}{0} \right]$, then apply [l'Hopital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) and finish.